# Get colors in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, control-characters

I have this:

```
ql_gray='\033[1;30m'
ql_magenta='\033[1;35m'
ql_cyan='\033[1;36m'
ql_orange='\033[1;33m'
ql_green='\033[1;32m'
ql_no_color='\033[0m'
```

I use them like so:

```
echo "${ql_magenta}quicklock: could not acquire lock with name '${qln}'${ql_no_color}."
```

but I get this:

```
\033[1;35mquicklock: could not acquire lock with name '/Users/me/.quicklock/locks/_oresoftware.lock'\033[0m.
```

is there some flag I need to set in order to get control chars to be recognized?

Is there some flag I can check to see if the end user has allowed control chars to be recognized? If they aren't recognized, then I can just set the above to:

```
ql_gray=''
ql_magenta=''
ql_cyan=''
ql_orange=''
ql_green=''
ql_no_color=''
```

I need to support Bash versions 3+.

Comment: Try using `printf` instead of `echo`.  See [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)

Comment: ahhh I think `echo -e` with the -e flag might do it

Comment: I need to support bash versions < 4, looks like `printf` is 4.1.x

Comment: @AlexanderMills `printf` is certainly in bash 3.2.

Comment: `printf` is specified by POSIX.  That's the point.  It essentially doesn't matter what version you use.

Comment: oh I read somewhere that printf was available starting with bash version 4, but I guess I don't know what I am talking about since I guess POSIX is totally independent/lower level than bash idk lol

Comment: iow, I was under the impression that printf was bash specific, I didn't know it wasn't only a bash thing lol

Comment: @AlexanderMills `printf` and its standard format specifiers aren't bash specific, but bash has some extras like `%b`, `%q` and the `-v` option, which might not be in dash's `printf`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portable way to do this is to use [`tput`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html):

```
ql_gray=$(tput setaf 7)
ql_magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
ql_cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
ql_orange=$(tput setaf 3)
ql_green=$(tput setaf 2)
ql_no_color=$(tput sgr0)
```

This will take the current terminal settings into account. The official colour list is documented in [the `terminfo(5)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html), but you might need to experiment — for example in the list above, 7 is officially white (but ends up light gray in most terminals), and 3 is officially yellow (but ends up dark yellow or orange in most terminals). You can disable colours by setting `TERM=dumb` before calling `tput`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get bash to interpret the escape sequences in the strings there. You can use either of:

```
echo -e "${ql_gray}..."
printf "%b\n" "${ql_gray}..."
```

Or evaluate them when setting the variables:

```
ql_gray=$'\033[1;30m'
```

Then either of:

```
echo "${ql_gray}..."
printf "%s\n" "${ql_gray}..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `echo`, use `echo -e`, using that flag will recognize control chars.

`printf` might work too, it's a POSIX thing apparently